# writing on images

Tags: css, html

This HTML code not working at IE 9. But it's working at Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Please help me. Thanks.

http://codepaste.net/kcbyv5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be your `float:left;`?

You've got a type: `flot`

```
#dis{
    position: relative;
    flot:left;
}
```

Regardless, I've tested this in IE9, and I can't find an issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/eQxZU/1/

Comment: @Mayk Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, Curt. not "flot"
TRUE: float

Comment: Brilliant :) Please mark as answer so others know it is sorted!